# How to convert epub into a format readable on Android based Phones/operating system

Tags: iphone, epub, ibooks

I have made and ebook (in epub format to post on apple ibookstore), is there a way I can convert epub into a format readable on Android based phones/operating system ?

your reply will be highly appreciated, Thanks a lot in advance :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android devices are able to open ePub books/documents. There are several ePub applications available in the Android Market.

Take a look here:
https://market.android.com/search?q=epub&so=1&c=apps

Which means you don't actually need to convert your ePub to any other format. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks ! that worked - but the only problem now is that Ihave embedded font into epub and that font gets gibrish. so my new question is how to read font embedded books into Android phones.

Comment: @Ballu - Many Thanks for the reply, I agree with your point (Since I have made this Epub I know all this already). what I am actually looking is the way I can convert it into a format that is readable on Android phones.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to convert a epub in to readble form is this - first compress epub then open it again it will generate some meta data related to epub files and you can fetch the data from the generated files because these files will be in the html and xml.In the generated file you will get the all infroamtion of the epub from content.opf , meta.inf(xmlfiles),toc.ncx.

Thanks,